# Word or phrase to describe something that previously had a use, but now has a negative impact

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

Something like a remnant of a system that originally had a purpose, but has since lost its purpose, to the point of having a negative impact on the current system.

Think of something like an outdated technology, that currently has a range of issues. In it's prime, it was a good choice, but now it is causing more issues than it solves.

Real world examples:

> 'The system contains x technology, likely a [insert word here] from when the system was first designed.'
>
> 'The human body still has a [insert word here] tailbone.' (nowadays causing more problems than it has benefits)

Answer (score 3):

In the second case you mentioned, the technical term is "Vestigial"

In general, you could use the term "Obsolete"

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system

**Legacy** - In computing, a legacy system is an old method, technology, computer system, or application program, "of, relating to, or being a previous or outdated computer system,"[1] yet still in use.

https://www.gavant.com/library/what-are-the-biggest-problems-with-legacy-software/

> Here are some of the problems with legacy software and the reasons why
>   systems need to be replaced:

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/vestigial

**Vestigial** - forming a very small remnant of something that was once much larger or more noticeable.  "he felt a vestigial flicker of anger from last night"

Biology - (of an organ or part of the body) degenerate, rudimentary, or atrophied, having become functionless in the course of evolution. [Vestigial organs can become detrimental: appendicitis or impacted wisdom teeth, for example.]

Answer (score 2):

`Outdated` or `Obsolete` would fit for the first sentence.

> The system contains x technology, likely an `outdated/obsolete` piece of equipment/software from when the system was first designed.

As @Arunkgp mentioned, "Vestigial" is the technical term, but it doesn't mean that it's presence has negative/bad impact. It means that it doesn't have any function anymore.

I'm not sure if the word you're looking for would fit both the sentences.

Comment: "Antiquated" is a bit stronger.

Comment: Doesn't vestigial mean 'not fully developed'? Antiquated may not be negative; it may have a vintage value  :), obsolete is not old, but a byproduct of ongoing activities/ processes etc. Interesting collection... :)

Answer (score 2):

How about **[artifact](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artifact)** (M-W): something arising from or associated with an earlier time especially when regarded as no longer appropriate, relevant, or important

An **artifact** could have negative (*no longer appropriate*) or neutral (*no longer relevant or important*) effects.

Your example sentences:

> The system contains x technology, likely an **artifact** from when the system was first designed.
>
> The human body still has a tailbone, an **artifact** of the evolution of *homo sapiens*.

In any event, it's a single word that works in both sentences.

**UPDATE**: Another noun that works is **vestige**. From Cambridge:

**[vestige](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vestige)**: a small part or amount of something larger, stronger, or more important that still exists from something that existed in the past

Your example sentences:

> The system contains x technology, likely a **vestige** from when the system was first designed.
>
> The human body still has a tailbone, a **vestige** of the evolution of *homo sapiens* from other species.

Like **artifact**, **vestige** is also a single word that works in both sentences.

Answer (score 0):

**Spoiled**

> (as a verb) to damage severely or harm (something), especially with reference to its excellence, value, usefulness, etc (dictionary.com)

**Time-corrupted**

**Fallen**

> having dropped or come down from a higher place, from an upright position, or from a higher level, degree, amount, quality, value, number, etc.

Though this does not include its biblical connotation that probably makes it a better fit